# Font-Awesome works on some servers, not others

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, font-awesome

I have font-awesome added into a web site I am working on but cannot get it to work on all of my dev and production servers. The styles work locally and on my stage server, but not on my dev server. I have checked my bundle.config and web.config files in all three locations and cannot find any difference between them that would keep this from working on dev. Here are links to the two public servers:

dev.colonyconcierge.com - not working here. There should be a fa-sign-in style on the login button.

stage.colonyconcierge.com - works fine here. Expand the sign in panel and you will see the sign in icon present.

There must be something specific to the configuration on the dev server that is preventing this from working but I have read all the blogs and checked all the settings I can think of but nothing has resolved the problem.

Comment: _"Insufficient data for meaningful answer"_  - Isaac Asimov. Any code to show?  See [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I check your sites,

you have a common and easy to solve problem, the link to fontawesome files are lost, for that  I have two theories:

1) you put the fontawasome.css file in bundle but you don't edit inside the links to fonts files, this file start with that

```
*/@font-face{font-family:'FontAwesome';src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0')
```

bundle made a mixed css file inside the directory Content so the code say the files are in Content/fonts/

you need edit that to pointing the good place in you project or put the directory Fonts of fontawasome inside Content/.

2) if you was made that and the problem persist, maybe you have a permissions problem, check if is possible read the directory and the files

Comment: Ok it was a publishing issue on the project. I did not realize when I published the files did not transfer over. Your description in #1 pointed me to the problem.